# Hyperbolic Identities

Tags: calculus

> Using which identities have given the following result?
>   $$\alpha cosh(arcsinh(\frac{s}{\alpha}))=\alpha\sqrt{\alpha^2+s^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $\cosh^2x=1+\sinh^2x$ then
$$\cosh^2\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{s}{a}=1+\sinh^2\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{s}{a}=1+(\dfrac{s}{a})^2=\dfrac{a^2+s^2}{a^2}$$
thus
$$\cosh\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{s}{a}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2+s^2}}{a}$$

Comment: Why do $1+\sinh^2\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{s}{a}=1+(\dfrac{s}{a})^2$? I get that $1+\sinh^2\operatorname{arcsinh}\dfrac{s}{a}=1+\sinh(\dfrac{s}{a})$

Comment: $f(f^{-1})(x)=x$.

Comment: Yes but isnt it the case of $f^2(f^{-1})(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: $\sinh^2\operatorname{arcsinh}t=\sinh^2(\operatorname{arcsinh}t)=(\sinh\operatorname{arcsinh}t)^2$

Comment: $f^2$ is not $f\circ f$, it is $f\times f$.

Comment: Correct my bad it is compostion of functions, got mixed up with the power

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

arcsinh$(x)=u,\sinh(u)=x$

$\cosh^2u-\sinh^2u=1$

and $2\cosh(u)=e^u+e^{-u}\ge2$